# Form element not respecting CSS vertical alignment in Opera

Tags: css, alignment, opera

I've inserted a Google Custom Search Engine form inside of a navigation bar but I just can't get it to center align in Opera. All browsers are respecting the vertical alignment perfectly (yes! even IE.. wow!).

You can check it out at [www.micod.cat](http://www.micod.cat) (the site's not in English but you can easily view the Search box in the menu bar, right). Opera is pushing the form input field flush against the top and that's incorrect.

Here's the CSS for that element:

```
#menu li.find form div {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Any bright minds to offer some insight please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, or what's going on, but placing an `&nbsp;` before `<input type="q" .. />` fixes it.

You should wait for a better answer, but if one doesn't arrive, at least this works.

Comment: It seems that Strict doctype does it, but also a tiny little `&nbsp` ... And well, changing the DOCTYPE has arisen a whole lot of other side effects with other areas of the site so, I guess the tiny, but not insignificant, little white space wins by a mile!

Another case of David (white space) beating Goliath (doctype) !!!!

I can't be grateful enough. Thanks a lot guys. **You rock!!**

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the Doctype, changing it to a strict one or an HTML one fixes it e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
```

The XHTML transitional Doctype means Opera renders in "Almost Standards" mode, though quite why that would affect this I don't know, - [Opera Doctype Switches](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto28/doctypes/)

Comment: If you're right (I didn't test; I assume you did): nice catch!

Comment: The Doctype does in fact work, but it also destroys other sections of the currently working website, which of course si a pain in the **tt to fix. So, I've decided to go with the simplistic and magical solution proposed by @thirtydot, a wonderful and beautiful `&nbsp`... taaadaaaa!!! Thank you anyway. I would never have thought of the Doctype having anything to do with it anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the content you want to align, but the image inside the content.

```
#menu li.find form div img{ vertical-align: middle; }
```

and looking at your site you'll need:

```
#menu ul.nav li.find { padding-top: 10px; }
```

Comment: There aren't any `img` elements inside `li.find`, so that won't do anything. Adding the `padding-top` will fix Opera, but break all other browsers. You should use Dragonfly to try out ideas beforehand (`CTRL+SHIFT+I`).

Comment: I did use Dragonfly for the fixes I posted but I see it'll break other browsers, take a look at the DOCTYPE post by @clairesuzy